# Angular : evaluate custom string at runtime

Tags: angular

I would like to create a breadcrumb for my Angular application.
The content is configured through the routing :

```
data: {
  title: '{{myTitle | myFormat }}',
  breadcrumb: 'Step {{myTitle | myFormat }}'
}
```

Those 2 properties must be evaluated on component rendering.

In my research of solutions, it found informations about the creation of a compile directive creating a component at runtime :

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[compile]'
})
export class CompileDirective implements OnChanges {
  @Input() compile: string;
  @Input() compileContext: any;

  compRef: ComponentRef<any>;

  constructor(private vcRef: ViewContainerRef, private compiler: Compiler) {
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    if (!this.compile) {
      if (this.compRef) {
        this.updateProperties();
        return;
      }
      throw Error('You forgot to provide template');
    }

    this.vcRef.clear();
    this.compRef = null;

    const component = this.createDynamicComponent(this.compile);
    const module = this.createDynamicModule(component);
    this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(module)
      .then((moduleWithFactories: ModuleWithComponentFactories<any>) => {
        let compFactory = moduleWithFactories.componentFactories.find(x => x.componentType === component);

        this.compRef = this.vcRef.createComponent(compFactory);
        this.updateProperties();
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  updateProperties() {
    for (var prop in this.compileContext) {
      this.compRef.instance[prop] = this.compileContext[prop];
    }
  }

  private createDynamicComponent(template: string) {
    @Component({
      selector: 'custom-dynamic-component',
      template: template,
    })
    class CustomDynamicComponent {

      constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
      }
    }

    return CustomDynamicComponent;
  }

  private createDynamicModule(component: Type<any>) {
    @NgModule({
      // You might need other modules, providers, etc...
      // Note that whatever components you want to be able
      // to render dynamically must be known to this module
      imports: [CommonModule],
      declarations: [component, IbanPipe]
    })
    class DynamicModule {
    }

    return DynamicModule;
  }
}
```

In the breadcrumb, it's used like this :

```html
<ng-container *compile="getTitle(); context:context"></ng-container>
```

All is working fine after a "ng serve". But, when I execute a "ng build", an error is thrown :

```
ERROR in src/app/directive/compile.directive.ts:63:17 - error NG1010: template must be a string

63       template: template,
                   ~~~~~~~~
src/app/directive/compile.directive.ts:80:21 - error NG1010: Value at position 0 in the NgModule.declarations of DynamicModule is not a reference: [object Object]

80       declarations: [component]
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Do you have a solution for me ? :)

Comment: Can you try your build again, but this time run this command: `ng build --aot=false --build-optimizer=false`. I suspect you may need to use the JIT compiler and not the AOT compiler.

Comment: You're right. It works.
Thank you very much